# like clause on all columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to use the like clause to search all columns in a row.
something like

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE '%something%' IN *
```

also, I don't know the exact columns that I have, this is why i need a wildcard (*)

there is a way to do that with snowflake / SQL?

Comment: I don't know how snowflake works but if you need all the columns to be searched then you have to mention it explicitly within the SQL query or some sort of dynamic SQL otherwise.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I dont know to columns of the table, so I need to use a wildcard (*) or something like that

Comment: I'm no expert in Snowflake or how CPU is billed (if it is billed at all), but doing this is not a regular requirement.  It will take some significant CPU to do this sort of string searching on a larger dataset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may consider using array_construct and array_contains:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TABLE test ( id number, v varchar, z varchar )
as SELECT * FROM VALUES 
(1, 'Gokhan', 'Aylin'),
(2, 'Joe', 'Black');


SELECT *, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT( * ) combined 
FROM test where ARRAY_CONTAINS( 'Gokhan'::variant, combined  );
```

You can also convert this array to varchar to search partly matching strings:

```
SELECT *, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT( * ) combined 
FROM test 
WHERE combined::VARCHAR LIKE '%Go%'; 

+----+--------+-------+------------------------+
| ID |   V    |   Z   | COMBINED               |
+----+--------+-------+------------------------+
|  1 | Gokhan | Aylin | [ 1, "Gokhan", "Aylin" |
+----+--------+-------+------------------------+
```

Comment: How to make this case insensitive?

Comment: @Andrew you can use ILIKE instead of LIKE to search case-insensitive

Comment: @GokhanAtil I was focusing on the first code block, but now I see how ILIKE fits in the second code block. I tested it, and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for 'something'  in all columns you can try to concatenate all columns in the where clause:

```
SELECT * from TABLE where CONCAT(colum1,column2,column3) LIKE '%something%'
```

Remember to cast to string type any non string type column.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentation the problem that I don't know the columns. I want to use a wildcard (*)

Comment: I'm honestly not aware of a direct method. I'm afraid you have to use a bit of coding to achieve it; like first run a describe command to grab column names and type and then reuse it in the CONCAT

Comment: @NirBerko There is no way to query columns in a database table without specifying the columns. If you're building the SQL dynamically then possibly you could query the metadata first to get a list of columns of type varchar and then concat them as suggested above.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths yes, this is what I did. this is so strange that there is a query in snowflake `SHOW COLUMN IS TABLE table` and it's not possible to use it within regular queries

Comment: @NirBerko if you want to use the output from a command like SHOW COLUMNS use RESULT_SCAN and LAST_QUERY_ID functions to get the output, examples here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html Alternatively you can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views instead to get similar information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to little tweak the SQL, concat takes all data types

```
select a.* from (
    select *, concat(*) as all_col_data from snowflake.schema.table_name
) as a
where a.all_col_data like '%something%'
```

Comment: am getting the following error: `Invalid argument types for function 'CONCAT': (TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9), TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9), VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216), ARRAY, ARRAY, ARRAY, OBJECT)`

Comment: considering your col data types, you have to write UDF. I don't think snowflake has any UDF out of the box to search all cols for the given string.